# Additivity for Relative Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $(X_\alpha,A_\alpha)$ are disjoint topological pairs, is the following statement true?
$$ \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha,A_\alpha)=H_n\left(\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha,\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right) $$

I would argue that this is true because
\begin{align} \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha,A_\alpha)
&= \bigoplus_\alpha \tilde H_n(X_\alpha/A_\alpha)
= \tilde H_n\left(\bigvee_\alpha(X_\alpha/A_\alpha)\right)\\
&= \tilde H_n\left(\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha/\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right) 
= H_n\left(\bigcup_\alpha x_\alpha,\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right).\end{align}

Is this argument correct? Do I have to assume here that $A_\alpha\subset X_\alpha$ is a cofibration?

Another approach of which I thought was to look at the commutative (?) diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\oplus_\alpha H_n(A_\alpha) @>i_*>> \oplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha) @>j_*>> \oplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha,A_\alpha) @>\partial_*>>\oplus_\alpha H_{n-1}(A_\alpha) \dots \\
@V\cong VV @V\cong VV @VVV @V\cong VV \\
H_n(\cup_\alpha A_i) @>i_*>>H_n(\cup_\alpha X_\alpha) @>j_*>> H_n(\cup_\alpha X_\alpha, \cup_\alpha A_\alpha) @>\partial_*>> H_{n-1}(\cup_\alpha A_\alpha)\dots \end{CD}$$
and argue by the five lemma that the third vertical homomorphism is indeed an isomorphism. Maybe I am overcomplicating things, but I did not find simpler arguments.

Comment: Conventionally one uses $\cup$ in things like $A\cup B$ or $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and $\bigcup$ in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ or $\displaystyle\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: you are right, thanks for the edit. But in the diagram it would waste to much space...